# JavaScript: Chrome and Safari trigger no mouse events when already-selected <option> of <select> is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to respond when the user re-clicks the currently-selected `<option>` in a `<select>`. Current desktop FF (v95.0.2) fires `mousedown`, `mouseup`, and `click` on the `<option>` element itself, and everything captures down and bubbles up through the entire `HTMLDocument` hierarchy, including the containing `window`.

In the same situation, current desktop Chrome (96.0.4664.110) and Safari (14.1.2) don't seem to fire any events at all.

```html
<html lang="en" id="thehtml">

<head>
</head>

<body id="thebody">
  <select id="theselect">
    <option id="option1" value="1">one</option>
    <option id="option2" value="2">two</option>
  </select>
</body>

<script>
  function logEvent(ev) {
    console.log(
      ev.type +
      '   target: ' + (ev.target.localName ? `${ev.target.localName} #${ev.target.id}` : `(${ev.target.constructor.name})`) +
      '   this: ' + (this.localName ? `${this.localName} #${this.id}` : `(${this.constructor.name})`)
    );
  }

  var eventList = ['change', 'click', 'dblclick', 'input', 'mousedown', 'mouseup'];
  var elementList = ['thehtml', 'thebody', 'theselect', 'option1', 'option2'];

  for (let ev of eventList) {
    window.addEventListener(ev, logEvent, true); // capture
    window.addEventListener(ev, logEvent, false); // bubble

    document.addEventListener(ev, logEvent, true); // capture
    document.addEventListener(ev, logEvent, false); // bubble

    for (let id of elementList) {
      document.getElementById(id).addEventListener(ev, logEvent, true); // capture
      document.getElementById(id).addEventListener(ev, logEvent, false); // bubble
    }
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Is there any way on Chrome or Safari to detect the user clicking the mouse on the currently-selected `<option>`?

Comment: Not likely. Events are not supported in some browsers for `<option>` and  are quite limited for `<select>` also. That's one reason there are a multitude of `<select>` replacement scripts around

Comment: The value of  a select doesn't change when you click on already selected option. What is your use case for wanting to do this? I've coded selects for 15 years and never run into a case of needing this event myself

Comment: You probably *shouldn’t* respond to that – it breaks the established/expected behaviour of a dropdown, which is a recipe for breaking accessibility. Maybe a separate button or collection of buttons would be better suited to the purpose, but it’s hard to say without knowing said purpose.

Comment: Y'all, if you're devising a highly responsive UI, sometimes it's useful to know the user decided *not* to do something. I'm coding for a small screen here, a collection of buttons won't cut it. Zooming out a bit here, the idea of keeping the DOM from detecting a physical mouse click (*not* a change event @charlietfl) at all seems a bit ridiculous. I realize it's enough rope to hang myself with — I still need the rope.

Comment: All I can tell you is there is no cross browser workaround for a native `<select>` Perhaps you need a select replacement that offers a lot more granularity. There are lots of them around.... like chosen and select2 just to name a couple. Also intimately familiar with highly responsive UIs. You are not likely in uncharted waters that many of us haven't been in before

Comment: To be clear, the spec says:

“The click event type MUST be dispatched on the topmost event target indicated by the pointer, when the user presses down and releases the primary pointer button, or otherwise activates the pointer in a manner that simulates such an action.”

https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-click

Comment: Well the click registers on the select which is the top most target. The problem with click on a select though is it registers on both open and select clicks and there is no way to differntiate. You are trying to re-invent a wheel that has been this way for many years. You can search the site and find many many explanations that options don't support events or even hiding cross browser. Similarly you will find many mentions that click on select is a useless event for a developer for the reasoning just mentioned

Comment: @charlieftl, you're mistaken about there being no way to differentiate. On Firefox, opening the select fires mousedown–mouseup–click on the select itself (not any of the contained options), but clicking any of the options fires mousedown–mouseup–click on the option clicked (plus a change event if the it's not the option originally selected).

This is completely sensible, and allows us to easily differentiate. It also happens to conform to the spec. Chrome and Safari seem to completely violate the spec here, and workarounds are clumsy and likely to introduce still other usability problems.

Comment: There is no cross browser way to differentiate. Just because it works in one doesn't help as you have already noticed. So I in broader reaching terms no I am not wrong. I admire your tenacity for digging into specs and testing in multiple environments and trying different approaches. I just know that you will come to the same realization that has been well known for many years. In early iE days the control was part of windows and I think it got convoluted then and never really got properly cleaned up across all the browser vendors. IE did so much to hold back the web

Comment: I appreciate your focus on the current state of things @charlietfl — guess I'll file bugs with Chromium and WebKit and hope they follow the specs!

Comment: Probably find those bugs already posted going back years

Comment: Hey if you do go into their bug reports and find anything of interest I would be interested myself in knowing what you find. Always wondered about this myself but as a long time freelancer I just worked around it and never dug in too far as it was not time well spent